# How to make button disable while moving to other view also?

Tags: ios, iphone, background, uibutton, nstimer

I want to disable button for a particular time:

**My Problem**

before time expiration, if i moved to other view and come back to same view, button get enabled.

**My question**

how to make button disable while moving to other view also?

I applied this code to achieve what i want..

```
UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier task =0;
UIApplication  *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
task = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{[app endBackgroundTask:task]; }];NSTimer *timer;
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(0.25 * 60) target:self
             selector:@selector(timerCountDown)userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0):

For swift use this code:

```
var button = UIButton()
button.enabled = false
```

Objective-C

```
[yourButton setEnabled:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable and enable with the help of Boolean value you have to maintain this.

with Swift language : -

```
//Create any Button property of Initialize here 
let button = UIButton()

//Then here you can disable button events.
button.userInteractionEnabled = false

//Then here you can enable button events.
button.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

I hope this will be help full for you.